# Photon2 billboards take a long time to face the camera

Tags: unity, c#, photon, billboarding

I'm using PUN2 and trying to use nametag billboards for my players, but they are not facing forward correctly and I have to wait more than 20 seconds to make the name tag of player return to facing forward.

here's my code for my `BillBoard` Script:

```
public class BillBoard : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected Transform ThisCameraPlayerBillBoard ;


    private void Start()
    {
        ThisCameraPlayerBillBoard = GameSetup.GS.ThisCameraToBillBoard.GetComponent<Camera>().transform;

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.LookAt(transform.position + ThisCameraPlayerBillBoard .rotation * Vector3.forward,
            ThisCameraPlayerBillBoard .rotation * Vector3.up);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks strange to me to do this action in `FixedUpdate` - usually we'd apply billboarding effects on text in `LateUpdate`.

Comment: Hi! @DMGregory i actually change it to lateupdate method.. but the problem is still the same.. i have to wait for 20 sec to make it work for the nametag of the player..

Comment: and the billboard is facing like 180 degrees in the wrong direction? hope you can help me...

Comment: Did you mean to use Vector3.back to point "back" toward the camera, instead of "forward" away from the camera?

Comment: With regards on the start of the game  the nametag works fine when i use the vector3.forward but every time the player died the nametag is facing 180 degrees towards camera  and i have to wait for more than 20 seconds to make the name tag of player back to facing forward.

Comment: That looks like something that should be in your question, not in a comment. By any chance, are you destroying and respawning the player's camera when they die?

Comment: @DMGregory yes it is. and on my player manager script  i originally assigned the target of the camera to the player like this:

Comment: player = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Path.Combine("PhotonPrefabs", "PlayerControllerBlue"),
                   GameSetup.GS.spawnPoints[spawnPicker].transform.position,
                   GameSetup.GS.spawnPoints[spawnPicker].transform.rotation,
                   0, new object[] { PV.ViewID });

                        cameraFollow.SetCameraTarget(player.transform);

Comment: and i also assign the die method on the player manager script

Comment: Again, that belongs in your question. Now: how do you expect the billboard to learn about this new camera after a death, if it only assigns `ThisCameraPlayerBillBoard` in its `Start` method, which is called a single time?

Comment: Okay thanks @DMGregory